# Distribution of the mean of normally distributed data

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, expected-value

I have an exercise which requires the following:

In water production, 1000 ml bottles are filled. The actual fill content is a random variable X.
n = 20 bottles have been sampled (independent identically distributed), and their content has been measured. It is known from past experience
that a normal distribution N(µ, σ^2) is suitable for the data.
What is the distribution of the sample mean X from the n = 20 bottles? Be as specific as possible?

How should I begin solving this problem and what could be the specific information which is require in it?

Comment: Since this is an exercise, the question qualifies as `self-study`:  you should indicate which resolution you attempted and where you got stuck.

Comment: thank you @Xi'an for the comment, I'm new here so I'll have that in mind, as I mentioned in the problem, I don't now how to begin with, so that's all the information I could provide

Comment: Well, you can at least add the `self-study` tag to the question by clicking on `edit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your samples are i.i.d. normal random variables, so their sum will also be normally distributed. It doesn't matter if $n=20$ or not. Even the sum of two independent normal random variables is normal. Mean is just a scaling applied to the sum, and scaling a normal RV produces another normal random variable. Your job is to find the mean and variance of $\bar{X}$, i.e. sample mean, based on the mean and variance of $X$.

Comment: thank you for your response, how would I go about solving them?

Comment: As a first step, calculate the mean and variance of $X_1+X_2$, where $X_1,X_2$ are iid normal RVs. Then try for $X_1,X_2,X_3$ and increase $n$ to $20$. As you go, you'll see that it's fairly easy.